# Windows 10 - Slow/Freezing "This PC"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

When loading "This PC", my Windows 10 installation often fails to display any contents (drives etc.) at all - or hangs/freezes. This is particularly true when an external HDD is attached. I've ran all typical diagnostic tools and tests (sfc /scannow, chkdsk, DISM, memory diagnostic, rebuilding the search index, disabling windows search, addressing registry issues etc.) - and nothing resolves this (nor are any problems found). The window itself loads but remains blank as the green progress bar indefinitely progresses with the message "working on it". Has anybody else encountered this and if so, do they have a solution?

EDIT: I do not have any anti-viral/malware software installed and rely upon windows defender alone. This behaviour is observed with several external HDDs and flash drives - new and old. I have updated drivers on everything.

Comment: Did you try using different USB ports? Are the drivers updated?

Comment: _I should add that this behaviour is observed with several external HDDs and flash drives - new and old._ Add that to your question.

Comment: from what you describe that does sound suspect of a failing hard drive.
To check this you can use a tools called GSmart:
https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads
or Simalar:
https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/crystaldiskinfo_portable run one of these tools and paste screen shots up and we can see if the hard drive is at fault.